# Sounds of 大体 (Approximately)　vs 代替 (Alternative)

Tags: pitch-accent

Are the two phrases having the identical sound (including the accent)?

- 大体 だいたい　(Approximately) (Dictionary: [OJAD](http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/search/index/sortprefix:accent/narabi1:kata_asc/narabi2:accent_asc/narabi3:mola_asc/yure:visible/curve:invisible/details:invisible/limit:20/word:%E5%A4%A7%E4%BD%93))
- 代替 だいたい　(Alternative) (Dictionary: [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BB%A3%E6%9B%BF))

I could not look them up in the same dictionary but two, and the two dictionaries use two different notations for the accent.  Hence the question.  (I am only a beginner)

Comment: 代替は is だいたいは【LHHHH】, but I feel 大体は is sometimes pronounced だいたいは【LHHHL】. I'm not sure if this is really standard, and I don't have any authoritative accent dictionary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to JL SE! To answer your question, yes, they have the same pitch accent: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84.

[image]

**[0]** means that it has a heiban 平板 pitch accent.